# Why does SQLAlchemy initialize hstore field as null?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, hstore

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and have a model with the following column:

```
class Item(Model):
    misc = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(postgresql.HSTORE), nullable=False,
                  server_default='',
                  default=MutableDict.as_mutable(postgresql.HSTORE))
```

When I try to assign fields to the model object, it seems that the `misc` column is None, rather than an empty dict:

```
my_item = Item()
my_item.misc["foo"] = "bar"
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

How can I configure the model so that new objects get initialized with an empty dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems here.  First, `default` should be a Python dict, not a repeat of the column type.  Second, `default` is not used when initializing new instances, only when committing instances with no value set for that column.  So you need to specifically add a default during initialization also.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict

class Item(db.Model):
    misc = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE), nullable=False, default={}, server_default='')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('misc', {})
        super(Item, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

```
item = Item()
item.misc['foo'] = 'bar'
```

---

<sub>On that note, there's no point in setting both `default` and `server_default` if you're only ever going to use this from Python.  There's no harm either, though.</sub>

---

<sub>I assume that you know you want an HSTORE in this specific case, but I'll also point out that PostgreSQL has the more general JSON and JSONB types now.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that correct way to define default value for mutable struct

```
misc = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE), nullable=False, default=dict)
```

it should be callable and works like factory or `lambda: dict()`

Otherwise, it can cause unexpected effects.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way to do this, but one way to is to create a custom column type that translates values from the database and back.

Here's an example from the docs that serializes/deserializes JSON in a VARCHAR field:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#establishing-mutability-on-scalar-column-values

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, VARCHAR
import json

class JSONEncodedDict(TypeDecorator):
    "Represents an immutable structure as a json-encoded string."

    impl = VARCHAR

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.dumps(value)
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            value = json.loads(value)
        return value
```

In your case, you could check if `value` is None and return an empty `dict()` instead, and when writing to the db you'd check if `value` is an empty dict and write `None` instead.

If you go this route, look at the mutability stuff a little further down so changes to the JSONEncodedDict get noticed and flushed. It looks like you already know about it, but just for anybody else reading this.

Hope that helps.